# Wicket generate BookmarkablePageLink or Link from URL String

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

My final goal is to generate a go back button in my wicket site forms.

Right now I'm able to get the referrer with:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)getRequest().getContainerRequest();
l.info("referer: {}", req.getHeader("referer"));
```

This works and I get the whole URL (as a String) but I'm unable to generate a Link object from this.

I'm not sure about the internals although I've been seeing the code for `Application.addMount`, `IRequestHandler` and more, I'm not able to find exactly where a URL is converted to what I need to generate a `BookmarkablePageLink`: the `Class` and the `PageParameters`.

P.S. I know this can be done with JavaScript, but I want to serve users without JS active.

Thanks

### Possible solution I'm currently using:

```
public static WebMarkupContainer getBackButton(org.apache.wicket.request.Request request, String id) {
    WebMarkupContainer l = new WebMarkupContainer(id);
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request.getContainerRequest();
    l.add(AttributeModifier.append("href", req.getHeader("referer")));
    return l;
}
```

In my markup I have:

```
<a wicket:id="backButton">Back</a>
```

And then, in my Page object:

```
add(WicketUtils.getBackButton(getRequest(), "backButton");
```

If anyone has any better idea, I'm leaving this open for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an [`ExternalLink`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/ExternalLink.html) for this.

Something resembling

```
public Component getBackButton(org.apache.wicket.request.Request request, String id) {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request.getContainerRequest();
    String url = req.getHeader("referer");
    return new ExternalLink(id, url, "Back");
}
```

with html

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="backButton">this body will be replaced</a>
```

And your Page object code unchanged.